# port old xcode project to xcode 4.5.2

Tags: import, xcode4.5

im new to this , im coming from windows c++,
and there its no problem to load VC 6 project to VC 2010
but now im on mac and i have xcode old project with x_myapp.pbproj project file
and when i load it to xcode 4.5.2 it gives me error. that its to old project .
how can i port/import it to the new Xcode?